Should there be a separate tag for the programming language R? What should the tag be called?
As the title suggests, this is about two questions:

Should there be a separate tag for the programming language R?
If such tag should exist on Mathematics, what should be the name.

It is outside of my area, but R certainly seems to be popular among people interested in statistics. Should this site have a tag for this programming language? What would be suitable questions for such tag?
On stats.SE (i.e., Cross Validated), they have a tag for this purpose and it is called (r). They also had some discussions related to this tag.
In fact, this is the very first question on their meta: How to answer R questions. And there are many posts linked to the question.
As far as I can tell, the tag called r was created twice so far. I found and one occurrence in December 2020. (In this case, the tag was relatively soon after the creation.)
And it was created again today - which is why I decided to ask on meta.
One possible issue a tags that is simply called r won't be sometimes use incorrectly. (For example, some people might be unaware of this meaning of "R" and perhaps they might think that it is for questions about real numbers; as they are commonly denoted
I tried to search a bit whether this tag was discussed on meta before. I did not find such discussion - of course, I might have missed it.

Not an answer, really, but I'm not sure that we need such a tag.  Most R-related questions are probably a better fit for [stats.se], so I'm not really sure that we need it here.  That said, I would suggest [tag:r-programming-language] if the tag is going to exist here (to avoid misuse---[tag:r] is likely to be confusing to non-R-users).

Hi it's me I asked one of those questions. I actually agree it makes more sense at Cross Validated, I just overlooked that forum's existence and posted here by inertia. Though I would say about the tag that if there's a matlab tag then it makes sense to have an R tag.
